# How to calculate personal number by date of birth using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make the calculation of personal number by date of birth.

The calculation is done in this manner:

```
Ex. 8 (day) +12 (month) + 1 + 9 + 7 + 1 (year) = 38 = 3 + 8 = 11 = 1 + 1 = 2
```

(the final number)

This final number must not be greater than nine.

So:

- The first number  comes is 38 greater than 9 and it should make 3 + 8
- The second number  comes is 11 greater than 9 it should make 1 + 1
- The third number comes is 2  less than 9 so it is the final number.

Taking all these calculations should let out the number 2.

How can I get it with php calculation?

Comment: Shouldn't you split the 12 of the month aswell?

Comment: Can the number be 0?

Comment: you can get the pieces using `date()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can split date to array. Then

```
$arr = array(8,12,1,9,7,1);
// sum array, split sum to array per digit untill more than 1 digit in sum
while (count($arr = str_split(array_sum($arr))) != 1)  {}

echo $arr[0]; // 2
```